# Disable horizontal scrolling for WKWebView

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, wkwebview, swift5

I know how to do this for UIWebView, but it is deprecated. I have figured out how to hide both the vertical and horizontal scroll indicators, disable scrollview bounces and disable the pinch gesture recognizer but still haven't found a way to wholly disable horizontal scrolling in the webview. Any help would be appreciated, below is my WebView.Swift.

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable
{
    let request: URLRequest
    var webView: WKWebView?
    
    init (request: URLRequest)
    {
        self.webView = WKWebView()
        self.request = request
        webView?.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        webView?.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        
        webView?.scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
        webView?.scrollView.bounces = false
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        return webView!
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(request)
    }
    
    func goBack()
    {
        webView?.goBack()
    }
    
    func refresh()
    {
        webView?.reload()
    }
    
    func goHome()
    {
        webView?.load(request)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you may use `Coordinator`. [There is good explanation for their](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/using-coordinators-to-manage-swiftui-view-controllers).
Create class `Coordinator` in your UIViewRepresentable. Add `UIScrollViewDelegate` to class. In `makeUIView`, set `webView?.scrollView.delegate = context.coordinator`.
In Coordinator, you need this function.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x > 0){
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y)
    }
 }
```

[And now, horizontal scroll not work!](https://streamable.com/iwk5zm)
All code

```
import WebKit

struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let request: URLRequest
    var webView: WKWebView?
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIScrollViewDelegate {
        var parent: WebView
        
        init(_ parent: WebView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            if (scrollView.contentOffset.x > 0){
                scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y)
            }
         }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    init (request: URLRequest) {
        self.webView = WKWebView()
        self.request = request
        webView?.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        webView?.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        
        webView?.scrollView.pinchGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
        webView?.scrollView.bounces = false
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        webView?.scrollView.delegate = context.coordinator
        return webView!
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.load(request)
    }
    
   // You funcs
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply and detailed explanation, it works like a charm

Comment: Done, apologies I am very new to stack overflow